# how to edit registry to let win10 password become never expired from auto expired

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, windows-registry, wmic

there is a way to let win10 password never expired by :

```
wmic USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='USERNAME'" set PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

I want to achieve it by edit registry,But I can not find the location of that ,
anyone help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Using registry ist not possible for that. Use "net User" in cmd or powershell

Comment: Users and Groups, Users, Your User, use the option to keep the same password and not change. Works from Windows XP forward to Windows 11.